# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, visual-c++

When I try to install *sklearn-crfsuite*, I get the following error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file
> or directory

trying this command `pip install sklearn-crfsuite`, also installed Microsoft visual C++ 2019 and the required libraries.

Please let me know if there is any solution to this, do I need to set any variable in the system path?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, add the path to your header file in your project using Property->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories.

If you want this to apply to all your projects use the Property manager to add this path.
Of course make sure the header exists.